# QuickSort Java code giving error Time Limit Exceeded

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, quicksort

I am using the below code to sort out a given array using Quick Sort Algo. I am a beginner and am struggling to understand why my code runs fine on few test cases but fails on few. I am receiving error Time Limit Exceeded. The code is constantly failing the test case :- `array{5,5,6,8,4,5,6}` . Feel free to give tips on how to code better.

```
        public static void quickSort(int[] input) {
            quickSort(input, 0 , input.length-1) ;   
        }
        public static void quickSort(int input[] , int startIndex , int endIndex) {
            if(startIndex >= endIndex){
                 return;
            } else{
            int pivot = partition(input, startIndex , endIndex);
            quickSort(input,startIndex , pivot-1) ; 
            quickSort(input , pivot+1 , endIndex) ;
            }
        }

        public static int partition(int input[] ,int startIndex , int endIndex) {
            int pivot = input[startIndex] ; 
            int count  = 0; 
            for(int i = 1+startIndex ; i < input.length ; i++){
                if(input[i] < pivot){
                    count++;
                }
            }
            input[startIndex] = input[startIndex+count]; 
            input[startIndex+count] = pivot ;

            int s = startIndex ; 
            int e = endIndex ;
            int sc = startIndex+count;

            while(s < sc &&  sc < e){
                if(input[s] < pivot) {
                    s++;
                } else if(input[e] >= pivot){
                    e--;
                }else if(input[s] > pivot && input[e] < pivot){
                    int temp = input[e];
                    input[e] = input[s] ; 
                    input[s] = temp;
                    e--;
                    s++;
                    }
            }     
        return sc;
        }    
    }
```

Comment: The code has modified Hoare partition scheme so that it places the pivot in place. This isn't needed. Instead don't exclude the pivot from the 2 recursive calls use quickSort(... pivot) and quicksort(... pivot+1 ...) . Take a look at [wiki example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Hoare_partition_scheme), which reduces the number of conditionals (if statements) to just 1 per inner loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a glance it seems you're using the indexes as a way to indicate subarray limits

```
        public static int partition(int input[] ,int startIndex , int endIndex)
```

But then you iterate the whole array always ( the condition is `i < input.length`) on:

```
for(int i = 1+startIndex ; i < input.length ; i++){
   if(input[i] < pivot){
     count++;
   }
 ...
```

So in your subsequent iterations you're still going through the whole array:

So in this call:

```
quickSort(input,startIndex , pivot-1);
```

`pivot -1` is ignored as you go through `input.length` anyway causing the guard condition:

`if (startIndex >= endIndex )`

to never evaluate to true hence running forever.

Try changing your for loop to (didn't try this myself, just by looking at the code):

```
for(int i = 1+startIndex ; i < endIndex ; i++){
```

And see if that works.

I hope this helps.

Comment: One more observation, if we avoid recursive call when there are just two elements in a partition (using one 'if' and one 'swap' if required) that will save some time as well.